# Tkinter: Text in Frame in Nootbook tab not painted

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

OS is Win7 64bit, Python is 2.7.16 64bit. I have a simple Tkinter GUI: Root containing a Notebook with two tabs. First tab contains a Frame which contains a Button. Second tab contains a Frame which contains a Text. The command bound to the Button spawns a thread with sets the content of the Text.

```
import Tkinter
import ttk
import threading

r = Tkinter.Tk()
n = ttk.Notebook(r)
n.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
control = ttk.Frame(n)
info = ttk.Frame(n)
tInfo = Tkinter.Text(info)
tInfo.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
n.add(control, text='Control')
n.add(info, text='Info')

infoMutex = threading.Lock()

def doGuiTest():
    try:
        infoMutex.acquire()
        tInfo.config(state='normal')
        tInfo.delete('1.0', Tkinter.END)
        tInfo.insert(Tkinter.END, 'Test')
        tInfo.config(state='disabled')
    finally:
        infoMutex.release()

def workerThread():
    doGuiTest()

def execute():
    worker=threading.Thread(target=workerThread)
    worker.start()

bExecute=Tkinter.Button(control, text='Execute', command=execute)
bExecute.pack()

r.mainloop()
```

Expected result: The Text is reliably visible with the set content after the Button is clicked.

Actual result: The Text is only visible when the tab containing the Text has been manually brought to the foreground before the Button is clicked.

When I set the content of the Text directly from the Button's command everything works as expected. Sadly, in the real application I am working on the functionality triggered by the Button will be running for several minutes so using another thread is a must.

What am I missing to achieve a consistent behavior?

Comment: I don't see anything misbehaving from your code. What do you want to achieve again?

Comment: I start the script and click the button and then the text isn't there. But if I start the script, bring the "Info" tab to the foreground so the empty text gets painted once and then click the button the text remains visible and the content of the text is displayed correctly.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. But I'm using python 3.7 so not sure if its a version problem.

Comment: I tired Python 3.6. I can't see the issue there either. Sadly, migrating away from 2.7 is not an option for me.